# CSS: Making 'list-style-image's position on the image itself change upon hover

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following CSS to change the list image on a webpage:

```
.footer-list  li
{
list-style-image:url('images/footer/arrow.png');
padding-left:14px;
}
```

The image is comprised of a hover/non-hover version, with the original on top and the hover version below it.

I would like this list to begin by showing the top section (7x7px), then move to the bottom 7x7 section upon hover. I know how to do the hover part but not moving the section of the image being shown.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: I don't know if that is possible with a list-style-image. You could set it as a background image

Comment: if you are talking about sprite technique so you need to have list item with fixed height of 7px, otherwise your image will be visible. So use other span inside the li element width fixed with and height and overflow hidden

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a `list-style-image` - the technique depends on being able to constrain the size of the image container so you can use `background-position` to 'scroll' to a different section of the background.

To get the similar effect on list images you'd need to split the image in 2 separate images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you're exactly trying to imply but

just try to add this css

```
.footer-list  li:hover
{
 list-style-image:url('images/footer/arrow.png');
 padding-left:14px;
 margin-top: 14px;
}
```

Please provide a screenshot also or url.

Thanks!